# How can I get the id or MAC address of my android bluetooth device?

Tags: html, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm beginner in web-bluetooth api, I want to get some ID or MAC Address of my android bluetooth device...
Or some way to identify each device through the API.
Actually I have this

```
// navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({filters: [{services: ['battery_service']}]})
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true, optionalServices: ['device_information']})
    .then(device => device.gatt.connect())
        .then(server => {
         // Getting device information
            return server.getPrimaryService('device_information');
        })
            .then(service => {
            // Getting serialNumber
                return service.getCharacteristic('serial_number_string');
            })
                .then(characteristic => {
                    // Reading serialNumber
                    return characteristic.readValue();
                })
                    .then(value => {
                        console.log('Serial Number is ' + value.getUint8(0));
                    })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`BluetoothDevice.id` attribute](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-id) to tell two similar devices apart. You can also use the [`name`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-name) if the devices have been helpfully named, e.g. "Nexus 6p (Bob's)". Here's a Web Bluetooth [Device Info Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html) doing just that.

You may find these limiting. Web Bluetooth attempts to expose Bluetooth concepts at a low level with minimal changes from the Bluetooth specification, but does take some action to provide security and privacy protections relevant for the web. The [blocklist](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#the-gatt-blocklist) contains:

```
# org.bluetooth.characteristic.serial_number_string
# Block access to standardized unique identifiers, for privacy reasons.
00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Your code to read the serial number should produce a console message directing you to the blocklist for more information.

See the Security and Privacy considerations in the spec related to [Bluetooth device identifiers](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#bluetooth-device-identifiers) for the explanation why these IDs are blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to get MAC address for a project. Do you know how do it? Something like that
 [chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices]

Comment: Web Bluetooth intentionally blocks MAC. See the Security and Privacy considerations in the spec, linked in this answer for why.

Comment: Note that I've seen some BLE devices that contains a custom BLE Characteristic exposing the MAC address as iOS also prevents reading the MAC address.
See for instance: https://github.com/beaufortfrancois/sandbox/blob/0eeeafd507dc93d2b0f9a2f2fb2a33eedf41589a/web-bluetooth/sense-peanut/sense-peanut.js#L64-L78

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with this method (getMACaddress), but on console, show this error Cannot read property 'writeValue' of undefined... How can i fix it?

Comment: The code I shared is specific to a BLE device. Which one do you have?